# Radix Sorting using using Queues

Tags: python, queue, radix-sort

I'm trying to create a Radix Sort that uses Queues to do the sorting.
The code I'm using for my Queue class is basic, but it works:

```
class Queue: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self, items):
        self.items.insert(0, items) #add item to the beginning

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop() # remove last item

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1] #First in line

    def size(self):
         return len(self.items)
```

To my understanding a radix sort uses 11 total bins. 1 bin holds everything. The other 10 bins are labeled from 0 to 9. The first round of sorting starts by removing 1 number from the main bin and looking at the digit in the ones place if that digit is a 0 we place it in the zero bin if it's a 1 we put it in the one bin and so on. We do that until all the numbers in the main bin have been sorted in the ones place value then we pull the those numbers out starting from the zero bin and place them back in the main bin and then start the process over at the tens place then hundreds and so on. It's also to my understanding that Radix sort only works when all of the data is the same length (or so I've been told. I'm assuming there's away around that.

So far I have this for my Radix:

```
def radix():
    mainBin = Queue()
    digList = [Queue()] * 10 #creates a list of 10 queues

numberList = random.sample(range(100000,999999), 10) 
#This would normally be passed through, but this is easier for timing
#the sort

for num in numberList:
    mainBin.enqueue(str(number))

while not mainBin.isEmpty():
    temporary = []
    number = mainBin.dequeue()
    for digit in number:
        temporary.append(digit)
        if temporary[5] == '0':
            digList[0].enqueue(temporary[5])
```

I stopped at that first `if` statement because I realized that I'd have to do this for 10 numbers that have have 6 place values that have 10 possibilities for a digit. That's way to long of an `if-elif` chain to write out (19 lines for one place value...), but it was the first thing that came to mind logically. Can anyone point me towards a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding the destination queues, you can just run a for loop and use the index.

```
place = 6 # In this case you know it, but you could scan data to find it.
while place >= 0:
    while not mainBin.isEmpty():
        number = mainBin.dequeue()
        digit = number[place]
        digList[digit].enqueue(number)

    place -= 1


    # Reload mainBin logic goes here.
```

To extend to the case where not every digit string is of the same length, you can pad with zeros as appropriate (depends which side of the decimal place you are on.)